# NSURLConnection (iOS, Objective-C) seems to be throttling after repeated sequential use

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, slowdown, throttling

This is an issue that's making me question my own sanity, but I'm posting the question in case it's something real rather than a problem of my own making.

I have an iOS app that is making use of the NSURLConnection class to send a request to a webserver. The object is instantiated and instructed to call back the delegate, which receives the corresponding notifications didReceiveResponse / didReceiveData / didFinishLoading / didFailWithError. Effectively the same code that is posted on Apple's dev page for using the class. The requests are all short POST transmissions with JSON data; the responses are also JSON-formatted, and come back from an Apache Tomcat Java Servlet.

For the most part it all works as advertised. The app sends a series of requests to the server in order to start a job and poll for partial results. Most of the exhanges are short, but sometimes the results can be up to about 100-200Kb maximum when there are partial results available.

The individual pieces of data get handed back by the operating system in chunks of about 10Kb each time, give or take. The transport is essentially instantaneous, as it is talking to a test server on the LAN.

However: after a few dozen polling operations, the rate of transport grinds to a near standstill. The sequence of response/data.../finished works normally: the webserver has delivered its payload, but the iOS app is receiving exactly 2896 bytes, with a periodicity of 20-30 seconds in between chunks. It is the correct data, and waiting about 5 minutes for 130Kb of data does confirm that it's operating correctly.

Nothing I do seems to conveniently work around it. I tried switching to the "async" invocation method with a response block; same result. Talking to a remote website rather than my LAN test deployment gets the same result. Running in simulator or iPhone gets the same result. The server returns content-length and doesn't try to do anything weird like keeping the connection alive.

Changing the frequency of the polling achieves little, unless I crank up the delay in between polling to 50 seconds, then everything works fine, presumably because it only ends up polling once or twice.

A hypothesis that fits this observation is that the NSURLConnection object hangs around long after it has been released, and chews up resources. Once a certain limit is hit, the progress rate grinds to a near halt. If the slowed down connection actually completes, subsequent connections work normally again, presumably because they've been cleaned up.

So does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: There's somebody from Apple who frequently responds to network related questions on the Apple iOS developer forums, if you get no response here, try posting or searching there. I've used NSURLConnection lots but have never noticed such a thing.

Comment: Perhaps posting your code would be helpful to analyze the issue. How many concurrent requests? How did you configure the request? Same or other resources per request (POST or GET)?